# How do I notice that a file executed from AWS StepFunctions has stopped?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-ssm

SendCommand is executed in AWS StepFunctions.

I am executing a file in EC2 from SendCommand.

If the file stops in the middle, I want StepFunctions to exit with Fail Status.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [Callback with the Task Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-token). Your application on ec2 has to "know" when it succeeds or fails, and send `SendTaskSuccess` or `SendTaskFailure` to Step Functions.